# How To Insert Two Variables into a SQL Table

Tags: javascript, sql, html, insert

I have been stuck on this for a while now and I cannot seem to insert two variables into a table. I would think this code should work...

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

function submit() 
{
    var input = document.getElementById("save_name").value;
    var msg;
    var time_stamp = new Date();

    db.transaction(function (tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id auto_increment, date_time varchar(128), log varchar(64))');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES (?, ?)', [input, time_stamp]); // <--Problem here!
        msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
        document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
    });
}
```

But it is not inserting my variables to my table.

Here is my printing function:

```
function display_fields() 
{
    db.transaction(function (tx) 
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + " " + result.rows.item(i).date_time + "</b></p>";
                document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML += msg;
            }
        }, null);
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you get any error message?  i bet your date is not formatted correctly...

Comment: Does the create statement work?

Comment: Jake has a good point - make sure that table exists in the database after at least one run...

Comment: @Jake1164 The create statement works when I insert a single variable. How can I tell if I am getting an error message? I am using MS Visual Web Dev 2010 Express. I didn't think it gave errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was by cancatinating

Here is what I did:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES ("' + input + '", "' + time_stamp + '")');
```

I know this opens up to SQL injections but I couldn't get it to work any other way.

Answer (score 0):

as a test - try it this way:

```
db.transaction(function (tx) 
{
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id auto_increment, date_time varchar(128), log varchar(64))');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS ( log ) VALUES (?)', [input]); // <--Problem here!
    msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = msg;
});
```

if this works, then it is your date which is formatted poorly.
also, you can add a trigger to the table to automatically insert the time as opposed to making the client do it...

also - do you mean to ad log instead of let id be auto_incrementing?

Comment: I have tried that way, and it does work doing one variable. I have also tried this: tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (log, date_time) VALUES (?, "SimpleString")', [input]); And it does work.

Comment: I am trying to add a new row to my table with only a time stamp and whatever was inputted. I don't think I understand your last statement, I do want to add a new entry for log and I want id to auto increment. But I can make due without id if that were the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in Chrome when I change the implementation of display_fields from

```
result.rows.item(i).date_time
```

to

```
results.rows.item(i).date_time
```

Comment: although that was a typo it didn't make a difference for me. Also using Chrome.